# Mapping git hash to deployed lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We would like to be able to understand the version of our software that is currently deployed to a particular AWS lambda.  What are the best practices for tracking a code commit hash to an AWS lambda?  We've looked at [AWS tagging](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/account-management/aws-tagging-strategies/) and we've also looked at [AWS Lambda Aliasing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-aliases.html) but neither approach seems convenient or user-friendly.  Are there other services that AWS provides?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without context and a better understanding of your use case around the commit hash, its difficult to give a directly useful answer, and as other answers have shown, there are many ways you could accomplish this. That being said, the commit hash of particular code is ultimately metadata and AWS has a solution for dealing with resource metadata: tags.

Best practice is to tag your resources with metadata. Almost all, if not all, AWS resources (including Lambda) support tags. As stated in the AWS documentation “tagging allows you to quickly search, filter, and manage resources” and subject to AWS limits your tags can be pretty much any key-value pair you like, including “commit: hash”.

The tagging strategy here would be to assign the commit hash to a tag, “commit” with the value “e63abe27”. You can tag resources manually through the console or you can apply tags as part of your build process.

Once tagged, at a high level, you would then be able to identify which commit is being used by listing the tags for the lambda in question. The CLI command would be something like:

```
aws lambda list-tags —resource arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:myFunction
```

You can learn more about tags and tagging strategy by reviewing the AWS docs [here](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/account-management/aws-tagging-strategies/) and you can download the Tagging Best Practice whitepaper [here](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-tagging-best-practices.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

One alternative could be to generate a file with the Git SHA as part of your build system that is packaged together with the other files in the build artifact. The following script generates a `gitSha.json` file in the `${outputDir}`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

gitSha=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
printf "{\"gitSha\": \"%s\"}" ${gitSha} > "${outputDir}/git-sha.js"
```

Consequently, the `gitSha.json` may look like:

```
{"gitSha": "5c805638"}
```

This file can then be accessed either by downloading the package. Alternatively, you can create a function that inspects the file in runtime and returns its value to the caller, writes it to a log, or similar depending on your use case.

This script was implemented using bash and [git rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse), but you can use any scripting language in combination with a Git library that you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to version Lambda is to Create Version option and adding these versions into an Alias.

We use this mechanism extensively for mapping a single AWS Lambda into different API gateway endpoints. **We use environment variables provided by AWS Lambda to move all configurations outside the Lambda function**. In each version of the Lambda, we change these environment variables as required and create a new version. This version can be mapped to an alias, which will help to keep the API gateway or the integration points intact (without any change for the integration)

Answer (score 0):

if using serverless

1. try in serverless.yml

provider:
versionFunctions: true
and
functions:
MyFunction:
tags:

2. try serverless plugins, one of them

serverless plugin install --name serverless-version-tracker
it uses git tags as version
you need to manage git tugs then